# Python's libxml2 can't parse unicode strings

Tags: python, xml, unicode, libxml2

OK, the docs for Python's libxml2 bindings are really `****`. My problem:

An XML document is stored in a string variable in Python. The string is a instance of Unicode, and there are non-ASCII characters in it. I want to parse it with libxml2, looking something like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import libxml2

DOC = u"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
  <something>Bäääh!</something>
</data>
"""

xml_doc = libxml2.parseDoc(DOC)
```

with this result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    xml_doc = libxml2.parseDoc(DOC)
  File "c:\Python26\lib\site-packages\libxml2.py", line 1237, in parseDoc
    ret = libxml2mod.xmlParseDoc(cur)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 46-48:
ordinal not in range(128)
```

The point is the `u"..."` declaration. If I replace it with a simple `".."`, then everything is ok. Unfortunately it doesn't work in my setup, because `DOC` will definitely be a Unicode instance.

Has anyone an idea how libxml2 can be brought to parse UTF-8 encoded strings?

Comment: `u"..."` is a **unicode string**, its internal encoding is not something you care about, it's not UTF-8.

Comment: Also applies to urrllib2, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

XML is a binary format, despite of looking like a text. An encoding is specified in the beginning of the XML file in order to decode the XML bytes into the text.

What you should do is to pass `str`, not `unicode` to your library:

```
xml_doc = libxml2.parseDoc(DOC.encode("UTF-8"))
```

(Although some tricks are possible with `site.setencoding` if you are interested in reading or writing `unicode` strings with automatic conversion via `locale`.)

**Edit:** [The Unicode article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky is good guide to string characters vs. bytes, encodings, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! OK, I guess I have to think again about strings in Python (although it would be nice of libxml2, if it would accept basestring instances).

Answer (score 9):

It should be

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import libxml2

DOC = u"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
  <something>Bäääh!</something>
</data>
""".encode("UTF-8")

xml_doc = libxml2.parseDoc(DOC)
```

The .encode("UTF-8") is needed to get the binary representation of the unicode string with the utf8 encoding.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works perfectly. Andrey was first, though.